# Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given site:stackoverflow.com

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I try to save my data in json with eloquent and i have this problem, i don't know why i get this error.

##### My Controller

```
public function facture_save(Request $request)
{
    $input = [
        'facture_json' => [
            '1' => 'One',
            '2' => 'Two',
            '3' => 'Three'
        ]
    ];

    $item = Facture::create($input);

    dd($item->data);

}
```

##### My table

facture(id, facture_json)
where facture_json is a longtext data format.

##### My model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'facture_json' 
]; 

/**
 * Get the user's first name.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
 */
protected function data(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value, true),
        set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
    );
}
```

Comment: `data` isn't `facture_json` ... where is the mutator for `facture_json`?

Comment: You don't need an attribute for this. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: I was just about to add that ceejayoz  :)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, please use a proper title for your question, not just a dump of the error message

Comment: Thank you very much, it work

Answer (score 3):

The name of your attribute function must correspond to the name of the field you're trying to work with; in your case, `facture_json`.

```
protected function facture_json(): Attribute
```

However, all this is entirely unnecessary. Remove the attribute function, and [tell Eloquent the column stores JSON data via a cast](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting):

```
protected $casts = [
    'facture_json' => 'array',
];
```

It'll handle the `json_encode` / `json_decode` for you.